# Can I change the icon of a VBS with out making it a shortcut

Tags: vbscript, icons

So instead of having the lovely script icon for a vbs, is there away to change that to make it look like something else? I know I can change it with a shortcut icon but then I'll have to have both the shortcut and the vbs. I tried resource hacker but that will only let me do .exes .dlls ect and not .vbs. Does anyone know a way?

Answer (score 1):

This would change the icon for all .vbs files, not individual .vbs files.

1. Download FileTypesMan - http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html
2. Right-click on Edit Selected File Type

From there, you can edit the Default Icon. By default, it references the 2nd icon in wscript.exe. Change it to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving it with .vbq extension.

Thanks.